# Commit Strategy Failed after many transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Running the Fabric test network with a very basic asset based chaincode.

Using the Java SDK to submit batches of assets. All works fine until I've submitted about 75,000 transactions. At this point, the following exception starts to occur every insert. It does however appear to successfully add assets.

```
org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.ContractException: Commit strategy failed
```

Looking at the ContractException, the proposalResponse for each peer appears to have the ChaincodeResponseStatus set to SUCCESS, and indeed the hashes of the payload responses match. There seems to be nothing within the exception to indicate something has gone wrong (apart from the presence of the exception itself).

A restart of the Java app using the SDK seems to resolve this until 75k or so inserts. No errors appear in the logs of the peers (or indeed the chaincode containers). If I add debug output to the CC, no adverse output is generated.

Answer (score 2):

The steps in the submit flow at the client end are:

1. Send transaction proposal to peers for endorsement.
2. Send endorsed transaction to the orderer.
3. Listen for block events from peers, and look through each block for the submitted transaction ID.

The way the block events are handled depends on which commit strategy is selected, but the default behaviour is:

- If an unsuccessful validation code is observed from any peer, the transaction failed validation at the peer, the ledger was not updated, and you get an exception to indicate that.
- If a timeout period is reached before a result (either successful validation or connection failure) is received for all org peers, a TimeoutException occurs.
- Once a successful transaction validation code has been received or a connection failure has occurred for all org peers:

  - If at least one successful validation code is observed, you're good.
  - If the block eventing connection to all peers fails without the transaction being observed, you get the "Commit strategy failed" message.

So this message is received after the transaction has been successfully endorsed and sent to the orderer, but then the block eventing connection to all peers failed and the client does not know whether or not the transaction was successful. It might have committed successfully. It might have failed. It might not have been committed at all yet.

The block eventing connections *should* retry and reestablish connectivity, but I have seen some cases where something in the network path is black-holing traffic for some reason. Since it seems to happen consistently for you after a certain number of transactions, it's just possible there is some issue in the client that is causing a failure over time, like a memory leak. It's worth doing some investigation.

In general, if you do have a transaction in this indeterminate state, a good approach can be to resubmit the transaction *with the same transaction ID* to the orderer again until you can observe the commit status and know for sure whether the transaction was successful or failed. Using the same transaction ID is important as it avoids the possibility of double-spend since Fabric will reject a transaction at validation time if that transaction ID has previously been committed, either successfully or unsuccessfully.

Comment: Many thanks for your very well explained reply - this makes a lot of sense. I suspect the last of the cases is what is happening, as its running on a (presumably well starved) session in docker on WSL2 - I would imagine either the loader is doing something strange or there is some other kind of resource starvation in the dev environment. Is there a way to listen on failed connections in the HLF java client?

Comment: You can add a disconnect handler for the peer eventing service in the client. Just be careful that your handler also calls to the previously attached handler, which actually drives reconnection. There is an example of this here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway-java/blob/c238fed497e996fe289c6a028c8de7b24accb2e7/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/impl/event/PeerDisconnectInterceptor.java